# Excel VBA error: Method 'Intersect' of object '_Global' failed

Tags: excel, vba

I need to adapt a PivotTable according to the content of a specific cell. The whole process works, but when I refresh, add, or modify content, I get the following error message:

```
Debug: Run_time error '1004': Method 'Intersect' of object '_Global' failed
```

It can be very annoying as whatever I am doing on the file produces an error message.

Here is the code I use (found on the internet, not my own):

```
Option Explicit
Const RegionRangeName As String = "SuppName"
Const PivotTableName As String = "PivotTable1"
Const PivotFieldName As String = "SUPPLIER_NAME"
Public Sub UpdatePivotFieldFromRange(RangeName As String, FieldName As String, _
                                      PivotTableName As String)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Application.Range(RangeName)

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    For Each Sheet In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        On Error Resume Next
        Set pt = Sheet.PivotTables(PivotTableName)
    Next
    If pt Is Nothing Then GoTo Ex

    On Error GoTo Ex

    pt.ManualUpdate = True
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim Field As PivotField
    Set Field = pt.PivotFields(FieldName)
    Field.ClearAllFilters
    Field.EnableItemSelection = False
    SelectPivotItem Field, rng.Text
    pt.RefreshTable

    Ex:
    pt.ManualUpdate = False
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
Public Sub SelectPivotItem(Field As PivotField, ItemName As String)
Dim Item As PivotItem
For Each Item In Field.PivotItems
Item.Visible = (Item.Caption = ItemName)
Next
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Application.Range(RegionRangeName)) _
Is Nothing Then
UpdatePivotFieldFromRange _
RegionRangeName, PivotFieldName, PivotTableName
End If
End Sub
```

The highlighted part of the code is:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Application.Range(RegionRangeName)) _
Is Nothing Then
```

I've tried to replace some contents (like `ActiveWorksheet` or `Sheet1` instead of `Application`) here and there, but with no success so far.

Comment: Which worksheet is the "SuppName" named range on?

Comment: What happens if you do this before the line which produces the error? `Debug.Print Target.Parent.Name = Application.Range(RegionRangeName).Parent.Name`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Runtime Error '1004':, Method 'Intersect' of object '\_Global' failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640397/runtime-error-1004-method-intersect-of-object-global-failed)

Comment: SuppName is ranged under Sheet1(PivotTable)
@DavidZemens The line does not solve the error appearing elsewhere
Else, is there a different way to filter a PivotTable according to a cell's content than VBA?

Comment: I understand that the Interescts must be on the same page. But here is the thing, they precisely are on the same page! It is when I try to change something on a different page that the problem shows up... =/

Comment: My last comment was not a solution but an attempt to disgnose. What does the debug.print show when you step thru that line?

Answer (score 1):

Might it be that the problem occurs because Target and the RegionRangeName-Region are not on the same sheet?

```
Sub mytest()
'---Throws "run-time error '1004': Method 'Intersect' of object '_Global' failed"
MsgBox IIf(Intersect(Sheets(1).Range("G1"), _
    Sheets(2).Range("G:AC")) Is Nothing, _
        "No Intersect", "Intersects")
End Sub
```

I found this example [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/671839-run-time-error-1004-method-intersect-object-_global-failed.html). If the above is not the case, can you use the locals Window to find the parents (i.e. worksheets) of the ranges "Target" and "Application.Range(RegionRangeName)" and see whether they are the same at the time the error is thrown?

Comment: Thank you for your first reply @user1965813 Your code does not seem to work, unfortunately. Here is the parents structure: Target (Range/Range) Application Range is not listed under this list though. The only sheet that shall be used for the macro is Sheet1. However, the error happens when I enter some text anywhere and the following shows up under the worksheet zhere the change happened: Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range) End Sub I hope it helps =/

Comment: I understand that the Interescts must be on the same page. But here is the thing, they precisely are on the same page! It is when I try to change something on a different page that the problem shows up... =/

Comment: Do I get you right, that you only have one pivot table in your workbook and that it is on the same worksheet as RegionRangeName?

Comment: @user2485354: If I get your comment from Jun. 17, 6:20 correct, then it looks understandable. workbook_sheetchange fires, whenever *any* workbook is changed. So if you change anything on a sheet that does not contain Range(RegionRangeName), then "target" (the sheet that was changed) and Range(RegionRangeName) are not on the same page, hence the error.