# Why clearing excel cell in vba do not work correctly?

Tags: vba, excel

Excel 2003 (on others not tested)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    For Each cell In Target
       If Not Intersect(cell, Range("A2:A100")) Is Nothing Then
            cell.ClearContents
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = CInt(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value) + 1
       End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

if delete string

```
cell.ClearContents
```

it's work fine, next sibling cell increments,

but with it next sibling cell value increases by several hundred

Why?

How to do this job correctly?

Comment: Try `application.EnableEvents = False` first thing when you enter the `Worksheet_Change` `Sub`, otherwise it will be invoked recursively every time you change the sheet from actions within `Worksheet_Change`. At the end of the subroutine (preferably also using an error handler) revert `Application.EnableEvents= True`. [This](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx) might help.

Comment: It 'works' without the `cell.ClearContents` because even though the *Worksheet_Change* is called again and runs on top of itself, the second time *Target* is in column B and it doesn't meet your `Intersect`. Still wrong, but it does run. Not recommended. Toggle `application.EnableEvents` as recommended above.

Comment: It is better if you fully qualify your `Range("A2:A100")`, see point 3 [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30363620/2707864) (only as an example of the countless times this shows up). Unless you explicitly do not want to, in which case you better implement [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27838913/2707864).

Comment: @Ioannis - Your comment is worth an answer.

Comment: @Ioannis - thanks for your comments and links, it's work fine

Answer (score 1):

Add Option Explicit to protect your vba from having undeclared variables and to eliminate the possibilities of Compile Error

Try this way it should work

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cell As Variant
    For Each cell In Target
       If Not Intersect(cell, Range("A2:A100")) Is Nothing Then
            cell.ClearContents
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = CInt(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value) + 1
       End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification, but your version also gives the same result as me, cell value increases by several hundred, not by one