# How to find max and min date in a range of another sheet?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I am writing VBA code to find the minimum and maximum dates in a Range. When I execute it, I get an error:

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-oriented error.

Below is my code:

```
Sub GenerateSheet()

    Dim i, r, numAssignments As Integer
    Dim ssrRng, DestRange As Range
    Dim StartDate, EndDate, d As Date

    numAssignments = Sheets("Data").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row - 1
    Sheets("Schedule").Select

    EndDate = WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheets("Data").Range(Cells(2, 8), Cells(numAssignments, 8)))
    StartDate = WorksheetFunction.Min(Sheets("Data").Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(numAssignments, 5)))

End Sub
```

Here, Data Sheet has 8 columns, Column 5 and 8 are dates

Comment: we do not typically put the tags associated with a question in the title as well.

Comment: Did you find posted here anything useful? Please post feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are telling range that its parent is **Sheets("Data")** but not cells. For all intents and purposes you wanted a range from Data!E2:Schedule!E99.

```
Sub GenerateSheet()

    Dim i, r, numAssignments As Integer
    Dim ssrRng, DestRange As Range
    Dim StartDate, EndDate, d As Date

    numAssignments = Sheets("Data").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row - 1
    Sheets("Schedule").Select

    with Sheets("Data")
        EndDate = WorksheetFunction.Max(.Range(.Cells(2, 8), .Cells(numAssignments, 8)))
        StartDate = WorksheetFunction.Min(.Range(.Cells(2, 5), .Cells(numAssignments, 5)))
    end with

End Sub
```

Using the `With Sheets("Data")` tells everything inside that block that is prefaced with a period (aka `.` or *full stop*) that its parent is **Sheets("Data")**.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks. Problem Solved. What am expert you are and what a great community this is. Kudos to you and everyone in this community helping each others. I don;t have enough reputation to upvote you or I would.

Comment: @R3uK - Not moving the *numAssignments* value assignment into the With/End With block was an intentional 'Easter Egg' left for the OP. And yes, I should have included a link to [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).

Answer (score 4):

You better change a few aspects of your code, despite not all of them being responsible for the error you get. They make, in general, your code more prone to errors (for instance, when changing code or applying it to other cases).

1. **Use of `Dim`**:
   `Dim ssrRng, DestRange As Range` declares `ssrRng` as `Variant`, and `DestRange` as `Range`.
   You should use `Dim ssrRng As Range, DestRange As Range`, assuming you want both as ranges.
2. **Use variables instead of explicit references**, in particular if those are repeated.
   Use

    `Dim ws as Worksheet`

    `Set ws = Workbooks(<your workbook name>).Sheets("Data")`

    `numAssignments = ws...`

    
   instead of

    `numAssignments = Sheets("Data")...`
3. **Fully qualify the ranges you use**, unless you explicitly do not want that.

   - Replace

      `numAssignments = Sheets("Data")...`
     with, e.g., 

      `numAssignments = Workbooks(<your workbook name>).Sheets("Data")...`

      (or, better, follow point 2, which already considers this point).
   - Replace

      `EndDate = WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheets("Data").Range(Cells(2, 8), Cells(numAssignments, 8)))`
     with

      `EndDate = WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 8), ws.Cells(numAssignments, 8)))`

      Likewise for `StartDate`. In this case, **these lines were the source of error**, since `Cells` without qualifier works in the `ActiveSheet`.
4. **Avoid using `Select`**, unless you explicitly need it. Declare and Set variables, and use them for referencing `Range`s or `Object`s you want to work with.