# Referring Cell range contained in variable in SUM formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have two cell addresses stored in my two variables 
saddr and eaddr (starting and ending cell addresses respectively)

I have to find the some of all cells in between the range and have the value assigned to another random cell. My code below throws an error. I am pretty sure i am not using the variable containing the cell addresses in the right format. Please help

Code:

```
saddr = Cells(x, 3).Address
eaddr = Cells(x, (3 + 6)).Address
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=Sum(Sheet1!:"&saddr&":"&eaddr&")"
```

The last line throws up this error. Can you tell me how to use the variable cell references correctly in the formula?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=Sum(Sheet1!" & saddr & ":" & eaddr & ")"
```

Even if this gets you going, you better check/fix a few things.
I strongly recommend you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30363620/2707864).